# Login_redirect_url not working. View always redirecting to index

Tags: python, django

This is my login redirect url in settings.py:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='/category/all'
```

And this is my login view:

```
def login(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        if request.method == "POST":
            email=request.POST['email']
            password=request.POST['password']
            user=auth.authenticate(email=email,password=password)

            if user is not None:
                auth.login(request, user)
                return redirect('/')
            else:
                messages.info(request,"Email Password didn't match")
                return redirect('login')
        else:
            return render(request,"login.html")
```

Whenever the user logs in I want to redirect him to the category/all page but it is always redirecting to index("/") and this might be because I am using return redirect("/").Also even when I have login required for some view then too even when the url is like:

```
http://localhost:8000/login/?next=/cart/
```

Instead of redirecting me to cart it redirects too index. Please help me to work around this so that the redirect works properly.

Comment: As specified, it only redirect to that if there is *no* `next` parameter.

Comment: The `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` settings will not work in your case since you are not using *built-in auth views*. You can redirect to whatever pages/urls by using `redirect(...)` as you already have done in the views

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem even when I have a url like this http://localhost:8000/login/?next=/cart/ it still leads me to index and not cart

Comment: @rohitbumrah: yes, because you did not use the `LoginView`, that will indeed redirect properly. If you implement your own logic, it will of course follow that logic, and not take into account settings. The settings are only relevant to the `LoginView`.

Comment: How do i use the login view of django. I have my own user model

Comment: @rohitbumrah: you redirect to the view, see answer.

Comment: Ya I saw it. I want to know how to use the `LoginView`  that is predefined in django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You constructed your own login view, hence that means that the mechanism to redirect will not work, since the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`, etc. are parameters for the [**`LoginView`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView) of the Django auth module.

You can simply redirect in your view:

```
def login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/category/all')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            email=request.POST['email']
            password=request.POST['password']
            user=auth.authenticate(email=email,password=password)

            if user is not None:
                auth.login(request, user)
                # redirect to a view
                return redirect('/category/all')
            else:
                messages.info(request, "Email Password didn't match")
                return redirect('login')
        else:
            return render(request,'login.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code, you are using return redirect('/') statement, which is redirecting you to home page.

To handle the redirections of urls like this - http://localhost:8000/login/?next=/cart/ you need to get value of next parameter from url, then write statement something like this. (Add this where you are using "return redirect('/')" statement)

next = request.GET.get('next')
if next:
return redirect(next)
else:
return redirect('/')

Sorry for not formatting properly,, I m posting from mobile